# Saving the output of the output of a random array?

Tags: javascript

So this function works fine, however everytime i refresh the page the WINNER (person1 to 4) changes, i want to save the output and have it FIXED so that it wont change everytime i refresh..
Basicly: There is a timer on my website and when it hits 0 , it should automaticly pick someone from the list as the winner... but the winner should appear on the website for everyone and stay there

```
function randomNavn(){
    document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        randName.push(nname.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * nname.length), 1));
    }
    document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = randName.join(", ");


}
var nname = ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4"],
 randName = [];
```

Comment: What is your `for` loop accomplishing?  It appears to be unnecessary as the code within it will only execute once.  Is it a placeholder for something that will actually loop at a later point?

Comment: To clarify, if you access this website on a computer and your friend accesses this website on a separate computer in a different location, should you both see the same winner? (This is the difference between local storage like a browser cookie, and remote storage such as a database.)

Comment: yes, EVERYONE needs to see the same winner!

Comment: If you want everyone to see the same winner then this should really be done server-side with a database and some server code. If you really want to do it in javascript you could use a pseudo-random number generator and seed it with some value that will (likely) be the same for everyone (i.e. the current hour in UTC or something). There's no guarantee that that would work though, as people may not have their computer time set accurately.

Comment: how do i this server-side then ?

Answer (score 0):

You need server-side code to do this -- and most likely a database. You can't do what you want from JavaScript. Each person's browser will run that javascript and get their own answer, bit it is only on their browser. Someone else will get a different answer, etc. That's not what you want to happen I assume.

Comment: what would you suggest i do then?

Comment: That is too broad of a question. You need to find web hosting services, determine what server language you want to use (what do you know? PHP? C#? JavaScript/NodeJS? Python?), and determine what database you want to use (MySQL? PostGres? etc.). Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. If you are just beginning, it would be better to search for tutorials on web development using databases.

Comment: i have a web hosting, i also have  contact form that uses php, therefore i'll go for php javascript if needed, but i do i really need mysql database for 1 thing ? this is just 1 thing only. 1 winner ..

Comment: Yes. You need the data -- that one thing -- to persist for all users of the site. So you have to store it in a central place -- thus a database (or flat file, etc.) on a web server.

Comment: ok so how do i do that? writing the result from a function, and on the same page write it , without people refreshing the page to see the result? like doing it live..

Comment: That is too broad of a question. Basically you need to use a REST service/API to read the data you want to show on the page. That is a very broad topic and if you've not worked with RESTful web services you should probably follow some introductory courses or tutorials.

Comment: you are absolutely right, what about php ? lets say i make an array in php and pick 3 winners from 10 , and use fwrite to write them inside a file like.. winners.txt , how can i call this php function inside the javascript function and how do i put winners.txt on the page inside html?

Comment: You use a web service -- and it can be as simple as a PHP file that serves the content you want. Again, you need to start with the basics and learn that first. Then by all means come back here with specific questions (and the sample code) if you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

To save data more permanently to be used in a web page, you have a few options:

1. Create a web service that accepts POST or PUT requests and saves the data on a server. This will allow you to share data between users.
2. Use a cookie. This will only save a value for each user's session. It won't share data between users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage:
`$window.localStorage.setItem('initData', {data: 'here'}`

Comment: i'm not familiar with $window.localstorage

Comment: Check this article out - https://medium.com/@tsinatzeree/javascript-localstorage-51fecb5e0b45. your data will persist until you close the browser. Including reloads. If you need something more persistent, just start a simple rest api with in memory storage, or a database.

Comment: So if i understood correctly (i'm also very tired) i can jsut use:
var x = document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = randName.join(", ");
localstorage.setItem('text', x) ?

Comment: I think so, then you can retrieve it as $window.localstorage.getItem('text'). remember this storage disappears when you exit your browser.  and you can see it by opening your browser dev tools in the application tab, under local storage

Comment: He can't use local storage for the same problem as using Javascript. All visitors to his site needs to see the results -- local storage doesn't do that.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. He will actually need a persisted data storage to achieve what he wants. Will edit answer/ or delete since there is another one suggesting to do that.

Answer (score 0):

after some nights spent i've managed to found the perfect solution.
1) I've eliminated the javascript function for the array and instead craeted a php file where a winner or more is choosed.
2) From that php file we write the winners into a text file.
3) From that text file we read it through ajax and list it when countdown is over.
If anyone is ever in need, its good solution.
Thanks for everytning